# Creating text-editable templates with abundance of graphics

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, pdf

today I'd like somebody with more comprehensive knowledge of graphic design to help me solve a problem with creating text-oriented and text-editable templates for my co-workers.

I was tasked with preparing a template (which I designed in PhotoShop) that will be edited by other person, using other software in order to change just text. However, that person is not an adept of Adobe products and needs an editable PDF or (the best solution for my co-worker) Word document.

For now I prepped the template in PS and saved it as a PS PDF then it can be edited using Acrobat DC. However that is still not the perfect solution.

Is there any other way around it? For example - use MS Word to prep the template or some other software (which I am not aware of, yet)? What workflow would you guys suggest?

Comment: Your question is still a bit too vague. Why is Acrobat not a perfect solution, how would you like 'the perfect solution' to function? maybe give an example of what kind of edits you need to do. MS Word could be used, if you lock all elements except for the editable text. The users would still be able to move/alter the editable text though.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 That would be a great solution - but how do I accomplish that?